# Spree i18n issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have a rails ecommerce site running spree and italian i18n trough those gems

```
gem 'spree_i18n'
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

In the admin interface, when I pick from the calendar an "Available" date for a certain product, it works fine just after save, but as soon as I re edit that product the "available" field is filled like this:

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: it.spree.date_picker.format">Format</span>
```

and of course any further save on that product will result in the product being unavailable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to this date picker localization change: https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/2220

try either updating, or adding the following to your it.yml localization file

```
  spree:    
     date_picker:
      format: ! '%m/%d/%Y'
      js_format: 'mm/dd/yy'
```